# Is it possible to make AutoHotKey show a message on (in)successful unmounting a USB device?

Tags: windows, cmd, autohotkey

So, I'm using AutoHotKey to safely remove my USB-devices using the script from [here](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?&t=4491). The only disadvantage compared to clicking the item in the taskbar is that the latter shows a message, either smth like "you can now safely remove your device" or "your device is busy, can't be ejected now" while the AHK script does not.

The question is: is it possible/how to show such messages when ejecting via AHK? Or, decomposing the task, how to a) check if the drive was successfully unmounted and b) show a corresponding message?

(I know, would be proper to ask in the thread [1](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?&t=4491), but I've got problems with registering there, some filter didn't allow to register using my mail/IP, don't remember exactly)

Comment: What are the values of ErrorLevel in those cases?

Comment: Ok, thanks to Forivin, I understand now that messages are shown using syntax `MsgBox, My messages without necessary quotation symbols`. I've added 4 messages before each return position, the first one meaningful `MsgBox, Looks like there's no E drive.` and the others for further investigation. Now I understand the syntax of AHK a bit, but still have no idea what ErrorLevel is (or how to use it). I guess if the last `return` is reached, ejecting was done successfully, but I'll test it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

In the thread it says:

**ErrorLevel**:
-1 Invalid drive letter.
-2 Neither a CD/DVD drive, nor a USB Mass Storage device.
-3 Eject failed. Refer A_LastError ( range 1 - 13 ) to [identify the reason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549728). The most common will be A_LastError = 6 which is
`PNP_VetoOutstandingOpen` *The requested operation was rejected because of outstanding open handles.*

So I would say, this should do the job:

```
USB_ERROR_LIST := [ "The specified operation was rejected for an unknown reason."
                  , "The device does not support the specified PnP operation."
                  , "The specified operation cannot be completed because of a pending close operation."
                  , "A Microsoft Win32 application vetoed the specified operation."
                  , "A Win32 service vetoed the specified operation."
                  , "The requested operation was rejected because of outstanding open handles."
                  , "The device supports the specified operation, but the device rejected the operation."
                  , "The driver supports the specified operation, but the driver rejected the operation."
                  , "The device does not support the specified operation."
                  , "There is insufficient power to perform the requested operation."
                  , "The device cannot be disabled."
                  , "The driver does not support the specified PnP operation."
                  , "The caller has insufficient privileges to complete the operation." ]

#vk4A::
    Eject( "D:" )
    If (ErrorLevel = -1)
        MsgBox, Invalid drive letter.
    Else If (ErrorLevel = -2)
        MsgBox, Neither a CD/DVD drive, nor a USB Mass Storage device.
    Else If (ErrorLevel = -3) {
        MsgBox, % "Eject failed:`n" USB_ERROR_LIST[A_LastError]
    } Else {
        MsgBox, The USB device can now be safely removed from the computer.
    }
Return
```

Comment: Could you please describe in more details how to use this? Currently I use `Eject` it this fasion: `#vk4A::Eject("E")`; where do I put these extra lines and how do I handle "no error" case for the `MsgBox, USB device can be now removed safely`? I've changed the content of the function itself but it seems that you imply some other technique.

Comment: ... The Eject call goes right before the If statement. For the case of no error add an `Else` to the If statement.

Comment: Looks like your suggestion is correct, but there's a problem with the script. I've tried to open a doc on my USB-stick and eject the latter via key combingation -- it tells me that "The USB device can now be safely removed [..]", but it is clear that it actually can't (it is not ejected according to taskbar/explorer). Same story if I add `Msg` inside `Eject`, before the each `return` (adding brackets where necessary) and the one before the last `return` is shown in both cases when USB is ejected and when it is not (because the doc is opened).

Comment: This could also be a problem with the library itself. Check what's in A_LastError and ErrorLevel. And does ejecting work at all? I mean if you don't have a document open?